# Get the Scope Identity

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a new insert which i then need to get the ID of the item just inserted

```
        var provider = new tbl_Provider
        {
            provider_Name = txt_ProviderName.Text,
            provider_Contact = txt_ProviderContactName.Text,
            provider_Address1 = txt_Address1.Text,
            provider_Address2 = txt_Address2.Text,
            provider_Address3 = txt_Address3.Text,
            provider_Postcode = txt_Postcode.Text,
            provider_Telephone = txt_Telephone.Text,
            provider_Deleted = false
        };

        //provider.tbl_ProviderDetails. = lst_ServiceAreas.SelectedValue;                       

        // Insert
        // ======
        _db.tbl_Providers.InsertOnSubmit(provider);

        // Save
        // ====
        _db.SubmitChanges();
```

How would i do this in Linq.

I have done it before with select Scope Identity but I am trying Linq on this Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. for more [info](http://blog.pureblue.co.nz/2008/02/04/read-inserted-id-from-linq-entity/).

```
        int Id = 0;
        provider = new tbl_Provider
        {
            provider_Name = txt_ProviderName.Text,
            ...
        };
        // Insert
        _db.tbl_Providers.InsertOnSubmit(provider);

        // Save
        _db.SubmitChanges();
        Id = provider.ProviderId;
```